# How to define a type that is a function with any signature but a specific return type?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that needs to be a function that when called will always return an object that has the property `type: string`, but I don't care about the parameters passed to this function.

So for example:

```
foo(1, 'bar'); // returns { type: '', etc: 1 }
baz('bar', new Date()); // returns { type: '', xyz: 2 }
bar(); // returns { type: '', etc: 3, so: 10 }
```

All of these should be valid for this type, because I don't care about the parameters I'm using to call the function, all I care is that it returns the property `type: string` when called.

How can I setup a type like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`type T = (...args: Array<any>) => {type: string};`